# Logs gzipped and not gzipped

Tags: linux, logs, gzip, logrotate, letsencrypt

Recently I've changed logs configuration for letsencrypt, because there was no given one and I have files:

```
letsencrypt.log
letsencrypt.log.1
letsencrypt.log.10
letsencrypt.log.10.gz
letsencrypt.log.11
letsencrypt.log.11.gz
letsencrypt.log.12
letsencrypt.log.12.gz
letsencrypt.log.13
letsencrypt.log.13.gz
letsencrypt.log.14
letsencrypt.log.14.gz
letsencrypt.log.15
letsencrypt.log.15.gz
letsencrypt.log.16
letsencrypt.log.16.gz
```

where even files have 1409 bytes and odd files have 0 bytes. Gzipped files however have some content (which differs). The configuration for log rotate is:

```
/var/log/letsencrypt/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 32
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 root root
}
```

How should I change the log rotate configuration to leave only:

1. first two files not gzipped,
2. rest of the files gzipped,
3. get rid of empty files?

Comment: Do you have two sets of cron jobs running tho log rotation?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, surely not.

Comment: @Kusalananda When you keep changing the log rotation scheme, either you have to rename or backup/delete logs. The old dangling names wont delete themselves alone.

Comment: Yes, I had made experiments changing the log rotate configuration but each time I've removed all the logs. No success yet.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't think your comment was for me, was it?

Comment: The comment was both for you and the OP, the you part is more a figure of speech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've managed to make proper log rotate:

```
/var/log/letsencrypt/*.log {
    weekly
    rotate 9
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    create 644 root root
}
```

So the difference is that I've removed `notifempty`.